# Two operations, one rule

Tags: mathematics

I'm making my own (esoteric) programming language, and after a while of using the syntax, me and my friend thought that this would make a great puzzle without context.

These two are mathematical operations, **no conditionals, loops, or anything else is involved**. There's just *something* that stands out about them.

The first one: `2 6 ^2 0 1-^^ 4 0 1-^*2 3++2*`

The second one: `2 4 8 2^*+ 5 0 7-*-`

The rules used to get their value are the same between the two. You must find the value of both operations, and say how you got there.

Comment: ... so is it rot13(cbfgsvk abgngvba)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the solution was easy. Please create an answer with the results and what you did so I can verify it

Comment: Huh. Yeah, I guess. :/ I'll try to research past puzzles better next time

Comment: @Avi is it sufficient that a puzzle uses the same method to solve (or even just have the same answer) to be a duplicate?  If so, it seems that would make a lot of questions duplicates!

Comment: @SteveV Considering that it uses the *exact* same method to solve, with that being the only element required to solve the puzzle, it's duplicate. If it were somehow cleverly disguising the fact that that is the method, it could perhaps stand (e.g. a grid of symbols where you use postfix computation instead of word-search techniques)